# 403 error running data unload with snowsql GET

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm having issues testing a data unload flow from Snowflake using the GET command to store the files on my local machine.

Following the documentation [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-unload-snowflake.html), it should be as simple as creating a stage, copying the data I want to that stage, and then running a snowsql command locally to retrieve the files.

I'm on Windows 10, running the following snowsql command to try and unload the data, against a database populated with the test TCP-H data that snowflake provides:

```
snowsql -a <account id> -u <username> -q "
USE DATABASE TESTDB;
CREATE OR REPLACE STAGE TESTSNOWFLAKESTAGE;
copy into @TESTSNOWFLAKESTAGE/supplier from SUPPLIER;
GET @TESTSNOWFLAKESTAGE file://C:/Users/<local user>/Downloads/unload;"
```

All commands run successfully, except for the final GET:

```
SnowSQL * v1.2.14
Type SQL statements or !help
+----------------------------------+
| status                           |
|----------------------------------|
| Statement executed successfully. |
+----------------------------------+
1 Row(s) produced. Time Elapsed: 0.121s
+-------------------------------------------------+
| status                                          |
|-------------------------------------------------|
| Stage area TESTSNOWFLAKESTAGE successfully created. |
+-------------------------------------------------+
1 Row(s) produced. Time Elapsed: 0.293s
+---------------+-------------+--------------+
| rows_unloaded | input_bytes | output_bytes |
|---------------+-------------+--------------|
|        100000 |    14137839 |      5636225 |
+---------------+-------------+--------------+
1 Row(s) produced. Time Elapsed: 7.548s
+-----------------------+------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| file                  | size | status | message                                                                                              |
|-----------------------+------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| supplier_0_0_0.csv.gz |   -1 | ERROR  | An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden, file=supplier_0_0_0.csv.gz |
+-----------------------+------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 Row(s) produced. Time Elapsed: 1.434s
```

This 403 looks like it's coming from the S3 instance backing my Snowflake account, but that's part of the abstracted service layer provided by Snowflake, so I'm not sure where I would have to go to flip auth switches.

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you really have a folder called C:/Users/<local user>/Downloads ? Don't you need to replace <local user> with an actual value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Windows-based slashes in your local file path.  So, assuming that to @NickW's point, you are filling your local user correctly, the format should be like the following:

`file://C:\Users\<local user>\Downloads`

There are some examples in the documentation for this here:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/get.html#required-parameters

Comment: Awesome, thanks for putting me back on the right path. I had started with the Windows slashes, but received a unicodeescape error. Looks like I just had to escape all the slashes, final line should have been:
>> GET @TESTSNOWFLAKESTAGE file://C:\\Users\\myuser\\Downloads\\unload